# Example of topological space $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff but not discrete.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Would you give me an example of topological space $(X,\tau)$ such that $X$ is enumerable, and $\tau$ is Hausdorff but not discrete. How can I construct this?

Answer (score 13):

$\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ in the subspace topology is Hausdorff, but not discrete.

Comment: ,thanks to you ,but i am really fool

Comment: $\LARGE{+1!}$ for you.

Answer (score 6):

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $a$, then $\{a_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{a\}$ with the subspace topology is not discrete because $\{a\}$ is not an open set.

Answer (score 2):

1 Appert Space

2 Arens Square

3 Arens-Fort Space

4 Closed Countable Ordinal Space

5 Countable Fort Space

6 Evenly Space Integer Topology

7 Gustin’s Sequence Space

8 Irrational Slope Topology

9 Irregular Lattice Topology

10 Minimal Hausdorff Topology

11 Open Countable Ordinal Space

12 Prime Integer Topology

13 Relatively Prime Integer Topology

14 Roy’s Lattice Space

15 Roy’s Lattice Subspace

16 Single Ultrafilter Topology

17 The p-adic Topology on the Integers

18 The Rational Numbers

More details on examples see [here.](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about such a site. Isn't the whole point of topological counterexamples that the student wastes hours and hours of time trying to prove the non-existence of something first?